# Add object with relation to database using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add an object with a related object to the sequelize database but I can't figure out how to do it properly. I've read the documentation but I don't seem to have the methods on my objects they're using.

My model looks like this:

```
Client = db.define('Client', {
    name: Seq.STRING,
    street1: Seq.STRING,
    street2: Seq.STRING,
    zip: Seq.STRING(7),
    city: Seq.STRING,
    short: { type: Seq.STRING(10), unique: true, allowNull: true }
});

TrackedTime = db.define('TrackedTime', {
    start: Seq.DATE,
    end: Seq.DATE,
    title: Seq.STRING,
    description: Seq.TEXT
});

Client.hasMany(TrackedTime);
Client.sync();
TrackedTime.sync();
db.sync();
```

First I search for the client using arguments read from commandline args (this works):

```
Clients.findAll({ where: { name: arg }}).then(function (clients) {
  startTimeTrack(clients, argv.t, argv.d, start);
});
```

And finally, the method that does not work as I've expected when I read the docs is this one:

```
function startTimeTrack(client, title, description, start) {
    if (typeof client === 'undefined' || client === null)
        throw "Please specify a client to track the time for!";
    if (typeof title === 'undefined' || title === null)
        throw "You need to specify a title!";
    description = typeof description !== 'undefined' ? description : null;
    start = typeof start !== 'undefined' ? start : new Date();
    if (!(start instanceof Date))
        throw "This is not a valid Date";

    console.log('\nClient object:\n', JSON.stringify(client, null, 2));
    TrackedTime.create({
        start: start,
        end: null,
        title: title,
        description: description
    }).then(function (tt) {
        console.log('\nTrackedTime object: \n' + JSON.stringify(tt, null, 2));
        tt.setClient(client); // exception here!            
    });
}
```

The exception I get is this one:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at startTimeTrack (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\bin\cmd.js:255:5)
    at C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\bin\cmd.js:221:6
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\bin\cmd.js:285:4)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\pr
omise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:
577:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:6
93:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\admin\dev\tim\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebir
d\js\main\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The documentation did it like I did it [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#associating-objects). I also tried multiple variations of that set-method (`setClients`, `addClient`).

*How do I properly add related objects to the database using sequelize?*

*Edit:*
This is the client object I'm receiving from the database:

```
Client object:
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Name Surname",
  "street1": "Street 15",
  "street2": "",
  "zip": "12345",
  "city": "City",
  "short": "ms",
  "createdAt": "2015-09-04T13:48:18.980Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-09-04T13:48:18.980Z"
}
```

**Notice:** I moved on with this small (and private) project and I'm just using node-sqlite3 to handle my 4 tables manually. If you, who landed here, have the same problem and one of the answers helped you, give me a hint and I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

FindAll will return array of clients, so if you want to return just one client you should use findOne.

Then according with [Sequelize Associations docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-many/) , you could use createAssociation , in your case (not tested) :

```
function startTimeTrack(client, title, description, start) {
    //....
    //console.log(client.createTrackedTime) --> must return function
    client.createTrackedTime({
        start: start,
        end: null,
        title: title,
        description: description
    })
    .then(function (tt) {
         console.log(tt.get({plain:true}));    
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't come back earlier. I'm still getting an exception `Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function` which occurs at the `createTrackedTime` call.

Comment: did you change findAll for findOne?

Comment: yes, I did. But it didn't change anyting. The resulting client object still has no function as member. I've added the output of `JSON.stringify(client)` in my question.

Comment: I'm also trying to find a complete tutorial or a small project that uses sequelize to learn more about how to use it. The documentation isn't very good. There's snippets everywhere but there is just nothing that shows how to use everything together... :/